# wordpress login issue with home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting login with profile page after login instead of front page or home page.
I want front page to be displayed to the user instead of profile page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress Login Redirect
A plugin which redirects subscriber level users back to the homepage after they've logged in

[wordpress login redirect plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-login-redirect/)